# Yii2 - error handler can not catches database exceptions

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm working on Yii2 advanced application project and I have a problem with **yii2 built-in Error Handler**. Here is description of my problem:

I have set `errorAction` in my backend configuration in this way:

```
'errorHandler' => [
    'errorAction' => 'site/error',
],
```

Now, the method `actionError()` in the `SiteController` catches every application exceptions, user defined exceptions and also fatal errors, **except database related exception such as `yii\db\IntegrityException`**. I don't know why, but when such an exception occurs, `actionError()` does not do anything! I don't want to catch exception manually with `try-catch` block and I want the central ErrorHandler catches **all** exception.

How can I fix this problem? Thank you all specially yii experts for paying attention. Please help me to solve this strange problem.

Comment: Did you disabled `YII_DEBUG`?

Comment: @Yupik No, It has `true` value.

Comment: Change it, should be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

According to this GitHub issue: [yiisoft/yii2/issues/10657](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/10657) and to the comment made by @Yupik you must change the `YII_DEBUG`.

If `YII_DEBUG` is `true`, you should see proper message about `yii\db\IntegrityException` in debug mode.

If `YII_DEBUG` is `false`(like in a production enviroment) error is redirected to `actionError()` and see it in a user-friendly mode.